VIM Adventures Level 7 Final Challenge
I've been stuck on the last challenge of level 7 in vim adventures. I have no idea how to move up to the line with the math problem on it in 5 keystrokes.



Based on the keyboard you display, you missed going back to unlock a door near the start of the level.


Once you have the g / G, getting to the number puzzle is easy.
First, enter the "What's in a name?" puzzle, and use tm to get "m" in your line-"until" finder memory. Exit the puzzle.
Re-enter "What's in a name?" and use gg; to get to the puzzle exit letter with one keystroke to spare.
Thanks for an excuse to revisit Vim Adventures, one of my favs! I hope you enjoy the rest of the game.
